# Осуществить поиск среди составных имен таблиц (user+date)

Tags: поиск, запрос, select, mysql

В базе есть таблицы, все бы хорошо, только вот зараза имена этих таблиц идет в виде `user20130425`, `user20130426`, `etc`. Как вы поняли, это `user+date`.

Подскажите теперь, как произвести поиск по этим таблицам? Скажем, мне нужно данные из этих таблиц в период с 2012 1 декабря до с.д, или 2013 фев-1023 апрель.

Что будет или как учитывать если февраль заканчивается 29? И не все месяца заканчиваются 30 числом.

Мои соображения: произвести дифференцирования между датой, и по формуле year*365+month*30 взять день и херить начиная с начальной датой, инкрементируя/преобразовав дней на месяц, год, и.тд.

Думаю, в результате получиться (точнее, хотелось бы получить) запрос в виде:

```
select * from user20130425
union
select * from user20130426
..........................
```

Что скажете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вот таким способом :

```
<?php
$end = new DateTime($to); //$to - конец периода,$from - начало периода
$sql = "";
for ($date = new DateTime($from); $date<=$end; $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))) {
  $i++;
  if ($i!=1) $sql .= " union ";
  $sql.="select * from user003".$date->format("Ymd")." where agrm_id=$agrmid ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то я не совсем понимаю зачем создавать было таблицы типа user+date... не легче было бы в таблицу user добавить колонку date и записывать дату, проблемы с поиском решатся.

Comment: Да конечно,это намного облегчил бы жизнь, проблем не было. Но не все бываеть как нам хотелось бы.

Comment: проблемы запросы переписать просто не вижу ну или же другой выход, перегонять через массив все числа месяца от и до даты, и добавлять как PREFIX к базам, только после названия таблицы

Comment: $array = array("20130425","20130426","20130427");
 for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user".$array[$i];
 }